# DAX PBI: Slicer return every values in the list when not select any option

Tags: powerbi, dax

i was trying to create a multiple choice slicer that allow user to pick multiple values on the list and the other measure will base on the condition and get the records with types = selected types. This measure will return a list of values. However, when i dont select any value, it return all the values in the list.

I tried multiple ways of writing DAX but it does not work

Here is my measure:

```
Remove_Cells_Parameter Value = 
VAR Selected_celltype = CONCATENATEX(
    FILTER(
        VALUES(Remove_Cells_Parameter[CELLTYPE]),
        Remove_Cells_Parameter[CELLTYPE] IN VALUES(Remove_Cells_Parameter[CELLTYPE])
    ),
    Remove_Cells_Parameter[CELLTYPE],
    ", "
)
RETURN
IF(ISBLANK(Selected_celltype) || Selected_celltype = "", "", Selected_celltype)
```

Comment: Can you add a snip to your question so we can what you are doing/needing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
ISFILTERED( Remove_Cells_Parameter[CELLTYPE] )
```

- It returns TRUE if one or all check boxes are selected
- It returns FALSE if no boxes are selected
- Important: It returns FALSE if the `Select all` option is selected

Comment: Did this answer your question?